# Issue with multiple graphs in one page, R

Tags: r, plot, panel

I am looking for a way to align mutliple plots in one page in R, while keeping the same panel sizes and distances from each other. I have four plots in total, two created with ggplot and two with levelplot. I have tried the followings but the panels are not placed equally. The levelplots (c and d), appear smaller and with a large distance between them.  Any ideas how to solve this?

P.S. I know that my code is not reproducible but my rasters are rather large to share, apologies. Hope this issue sounds familliar to someone!

```
plot_grid(a,b,c,d,  ncol=2,nrow = 2, rel_heights = c(1/4, 1/4, 1/4,1/4))

ggarrange(a, b, c,d,ncol = 2, nrow = 2)

ggarrange(a, b, c,d,ncol = 2, nrow = 2,heights = c(1, 1, 1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I took an example from `lattice` manual.

```
library(lattice)

x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
plo1<- levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
      ylab="", main="My title", colorkey = FALSE)
```

and a plot made with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

plo2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        ggtitle("My title")
```

Next, `library(ggpubr)`

```
ggarrange(plo2, plo1, plo2, plo1, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

... it looks not bad, I think.

Maybe, you should a little modify your plot (tune margins, legend etc.)?

I consider, it will be better to adapt a ggplot2 object to levelplot.

How do you think?